# Momentary Switching for High-Power DC Motor

Tags: switches, dc-motor, circuit-design, safety

First let me state up-front that I'm an aerospace engineer with very limited experience with electronics. Feel free to get technical, but please cut me some slack.

**Background:**
I want to modify an electric winch controller to include momentary switches that break the circuit and stop motion in a particular direction -e.g. when the cable plays out by X feet (basically to stop it playing out the entire drum of cable if left unattended). I figured this shouldn't be hard to do since the OEM controller uses what seem to be simple pushbuttons.

However, in the electrical diagram for the winch, shown below, it looks like the full rectified DC current flows directly through the controller. The winch is rated for 6A under full load, at 120VAC supply voltage, so there's a LOT of power going through those switches, and that makes me think there's more to them.

**Question 1:**
Is there some protective feature that I'm missing which prevents the controller's pushbuttons from arcing when switching under load?

**Question 2:**
What kind of momentary switches would I need to safely handle the power running through these wires?

[image: Warn 1000AC Electrical Diagram]

[Winch Technical Description](https://www.warn.com/utility/assets/pdf/81410A4_rs.pdf)

Comment: Hmm, The switches are on the DC side, they need to be pretty decent to handle 170V DC at 6A with an inductive load.  There are limit switch designs out there that use diodes to allow reversing from a limit stop.  Switches rated for 10A and 250VDC inductive loads should be able to handle your winch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install freewheeling diodes in parallel to the switch, or MOV varistors, or RC snubbers. 
The starting current is much higher than nominal, also I think you should place a thermal switch to prevent overload and shut down.